# Associative array populate in a for loop

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have to populate my associative array based on my API Get call. My script is like this where "get_fileshares" is a defined function that returns a list of files with name and id as fields. Now,I want to populate my associate array on the go such that for this JSON, my array should look like the following
My array should be:

```
name=07bff899-4440-4ba9-85f5-c3e47555dc0e
name2=07bff899-4440-4ba9-85f5-c3e47555dc02
```

JSON

```
    "values": [
            {
                "name": "test",
                "id": "07bff899-4440-4ba9-85f5-c3e47555dc0e"
            }
    
            {
                "name2": "test",
                "id": "07bff899-4440-4ba9-85f5-c3e47555dc02"
            }
           ]



declare -A a
n=($(get_fileshares | jq --raw-output '.values[].name'))
aa=($(get_fileshares | jq --raw-output '.values[].id'))
for (( i=0; i<${#n[@]}; i++ )); do
    #echo ${d}
    a[("${n[i]}")]+=("${aa[i]}")
done
```

error: cannot assign list to array member

Comment: "cannot assign list to array member" -- bash arrays are strictly one dimensional. If you need more complex data structures, you have to pick another language.

Comment: But I am not assigning a list as values. I am only assigning one key to one value. But obviously, my associated array has many K,V pairs. Is that doable in bash?

Comment: I plan to do this: a[n[I]]=a[aa[I]]

Comment: `But I am not assigning a list as value` - you are adding array elements to an array element - `a[...] += ( ... )` - there are no 2d arrays in bash.

Answer (score -1):

You are adding `+=` new array elements `( ..)` to an array element `a[...]`. Instead assign the actual value.

```
n=(name name2)
aa=(samplevalue samplevalue2)
declare -A a
for (( i=0; i<${#n[@]}; i++ )); do
    a[${n[i]}]="${aa[i]}"
done
declare -p a
```

Suggest to use way more descriptive variable names then "aa" "n" or "a"...

Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net . Revise some bash introduction.

Consider writing a better `jq` like `jq -r '.[] | to_entries | (.[] | select(.value == "test") | .key), (.[] | select(.value != "test") | .value)'` and not using `arr=(..)` for spliting elements. Research when to use quoting in shell, research word splitting and filename expansion.